# How to make non-accessible xampp server from network?

Tags: php, linux, apache, networking, xampp

I have downloaded xampp and want to make some modifications in php system.
My question is about, if it is possible to make xampp inaccessible from network (network administration does not allow to provide any services in net) ? It would be nice if you could provide specific steps/folders/variables to change.

I work with ubuntu on xampp 1.8.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make xampp only bind to localhost as opposed to all interfaces, thus making it inaccessible from the network. In the `httpd.conf` file (I think in ubuntu, it's actually `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`) where it says:

```
Listen 80
```

change it to:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Comment: Could not found anything with Listen in httpd-xampp.conf but found it in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf